# Why does this.health not work in this instance?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova

I am creating an app that uses healthkit. When I run the app, I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'health' of null`. I tried doing navigator.health, but get the error that health does not exist on navigator. I assume this is a fairly simple problem to fix, how do I correctly call health in this instance?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from "@ionic/angular";
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { Health } from '@ionic-native/health/ngx';

declare var shake;
var min_speed = 0.2;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-motion-analysis',
  templateUrl: './motion-analysis.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./motion-analysis.page.scss'],
})
export class MotionAnalysisPage {
  constructor(public platform: Platform, private health: Health){}

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.health.isAvailable()
            .then((available:boolean) => {
              console.log(available);
              this.health.requestAuthorization([
                {
                  read: ['steps'],       //read only permission
                }
              ])
              .then(res => console.log(res))
              .catch(e => console.log(e));
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(e));

      function onShake() {
        console.log("shake")
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {
          maximumAge: 1000,
          timeout: 10000,
          enableHighAccuracy : true,
        });
  
        function onSuccess(position){
          if(position.coords.speed > min_speed){
            this.health.query({
              startDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 10*1000 ), // ten sec ago
              endDate: new Date(), // now
              dataType: 'steps',
              limit: 1000
            }).then(data=>{
              console.log(data);
            }).catch(e => {
              console.log("error "+ e);
            })
          }
        }
      };
      
      function onError(err) {
        console.log(err)
      };

      // Start watching for shake gestures and call "onShake"
      shake.startWatch(onShake, 5, onError);

    })
  }
}
```

---

edit, [link](https://github.com/dariosalvi78/cordova-plugin-health) to tutorial, and I am referring to `this.health.query({` mentioning for conciseness. I do not get this error when I do not include that section of code.

---

edit2: Solved, just had to preserve the value of this using arrow functions or a new variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using V3 of Ionic install below plugins

```
    $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-health
    $ npm install --save @ionic-native/health@4
```

And in Component `import { Health } from '@ionic-native/health';`

Comment: I am using ionic5, any tips for that? I did install the plugin and the ionic-native plugin following the tutorial I edited into the main post

Comment: Main thing is, it works if I move it out of the function it is inside of. I am referring to this.health.query, should have mentioned. So I think it is an error with using "this"